# How to resolve terraform message: 'google_compute_ssl_certificate.xxx must be replace'?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm a Terraform beginner. My colleague used Terraform on a Mac to operate on GCP before, and now it's handed over to me on a Windows environment, I also have installed Terraform and gcloud.

When I sequentially execute `terraform init` and `terraform plan`, it show the message:

```
  # google_compute_ssl_certificate.xxx must be replaced
+/- resource "google_compute_ssl_certificate" "xxx" {
      ~ certificate_id     = 123456789123456789 -> (known after apply)
      ~ creation_timestamp = "2023-12-12T22:14:53.454-08:00" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                 = "projects/xxx/global/sslCertificates/gw-tweinv-20231111061452975600000001" -> (known after apply)
      ~ name               = "xxx-20231213061452975600000001" -> (known after apply)
      ~ private_key        = (sensitive value) # forces replacement
      ~ project            = "xxx" -> (known after apply)
      ~ self_link          = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxx/global/sslCertificates/xxx-20231111061452975600000001" -> (known after apply)
        # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

But I haven't modified the certificates files or contents.

---

I also tried the command `terraform state pull \> terraform-2.tfstate` to replace my state with 'terraform-2.tfstate', and then execute 'terraform plan', but still got the same result.

If I continue to execute `terraform apply`, will the existing server certificates and domains actually become invalid or change?

I'm only concerned about whether it will affect user connections.

How should this situation be resolved? Thanks.

Comment: This is what is forcing the replacement: 
`private_key = (sensitive value) # forces replacement`
So, it looks like what ever you supply in the private key does not match what is there in the state. If it actually has changed or if there is an error in code is hard to tell without knowing how you supply the key.

Comment: Has the certificate expired? Edit your post to include the HCL for `google_compute_ssl_certificate` with details for the certificate.